# How to append elements inside for loop in Bash?

Tags: bash

I have the below pseudo code:

```
#!/bin/bash
USERS_LIST=$(cat users.txt)

function exit_loop() {
    declare -a exceeded_users
    if [[ $SUM -gt 7000 ]];then
        echo $SUM
        exceeded_users+=("$USER")
    fi
    #CHECK LAST USER IN THE ARRAY
    if [[ $USER = ${a[exceeded_users{#exceeded_users[@]}-1]} ]];then
        break
    fi
    echo "${exceeded_users[@]}"
}

for USER in $USERS_LIST;do
    SUM=$(( $LAST_DATE_SIZE - $PREVIOUS_DATE_SIZE ))
    exit_loop
done
```

My goal is that the function "exit_loop" function will exit the loop once it’s looped all the users what exceeded 700mb, but looks like when I am echoing the array `exceeded_users[@]` I am not getting any output. I need to get the array value at the second if statement.

If you got another way to exit the loop once the loop run once all
all the users that exceeded 700MB I will appropriate that.

Comment: There must be some code to calculate `LAST_DATE_SIZE` and `PREVIOUS_DATE_SIZE`. Can you share so that it will be possible to suggest alternatives ?

Comment: Use `declare -g -a arrayname` to define a *global* array instead of a local one.

Comment: BTW, storing a list in a string is... not great; expansions are error-prone (if your file contains a standalone `*`, you'll end up iterating over contents of the current directory). Consider `readarray -t users_list < users.txt`, if your file contains one line per user.

Comment: You can't `break` from a function called from a loop. `break` has to be directly inside the loop.

Comment: @JohnKugelman In bash4+, yes. Bash3 allows it in functions.

Answer (score 0):

The array exceeded_users is declared locally within the function exit_loop so it will not retain the values stored between calls. Try either declaring exceeded_users before the function exit_loop so it is global, or declaring it with the -g flag `declare -ag exceeded_users` to make it global. (Thanks to Charles Duffy for pointing out the -g flag)